# Xamarin Forms and Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to have Unity and Xamarin Forms in a single app. We have a scenario where there is a business app written completely in Xamarin Forms and we need to build a wheel of fortune for incentives, which can be built very easily using Unity.

If this is not possible, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is not possible, are there any alternatives?

I think it's not possible for now, but you can use [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/introduction/) as alternative for Unity

Answer (score 1):

Since Xamarin and Unity having different mono base its almost impossible. Good news is Unity planing to use Mono 5.9 version which is same with Xamarin.

For more information click [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-add-ins-for-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-5-9.329880/).